# Instagram Basic API and Business Verification

Tags: facebook, instagram-api

I've had a working integration between Instagram and my app (https://phojo.app) for a couple of years. It uses the Instagram Basic Display API and I've gone through the App Review and Individual Verification.

On 31 August, I got an email from Facebook with the following:

> In order for Phojo to retain advanced access to the instagram_graph_user_media permission, the app must be connected to a Meta Business Account that has completed business verification. If business verification is not completed by September 15, 2022, advanced access to this permission will be revoked.

My first question is why I even need to do Business Verification for using the Instagram Basic Display API? Is the secret in the word *'advanced'* in *"advanced access to the instagram_graph_user_media permission"*? Is there a basic access to the API?

Second question is if there is something I can do to get around the Business Verification? Can you tell Meta that, *"Hey, I'm not a business, but I'm still a serious app creator."* Is there anywhere I can turn to discuss this with a Facebook support staff directly?

Comment: As this is a FB policy question, I think it'd be more appropriate to get clarifications from Facebook.

Comment: *"why I even need to do Business Verification for using the Instagram Basic Display API?"* it's the rule set by the company.

Comment: @ewong, I tried to comb through their Facebook Support pages, but couldn't find any forums or contact details. I looked around StackOverflow and saw people asking questions about the verification process, so thought maybe this post would be valid here as well.

Comment: @Raptor, I looked around the documentation and found conflicting messaging on that. One part said that you had to go through Business Verification, but in other places, it said Individual Verification should be enough. Quite confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem with my app, and I opened a bug report with them. After some tedious back and forth where I provided them with tokens, sample code etc., they came back with this response:

> Due to a recent change, Individual Verification has been removed for
> the 'instagram_graph_user_media' permission and in order to retain
> access to the permission, the app must be connected to a Meta Business
> Account that has completed business verification. You may read more
> about business verification here:
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release/business-verification
>
> We apologize for the inconvenience this might have caused.

There is no way around this, and you have to go through setting up a business and a business account to continue offering your app.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Good to know someone managed to het in touch with support and get a hard answer on this. not the one I hoped for, but, oh well.

Comment: Hello! In order to have a business meta account, it has to be a verified business. So did you end up registering a business? I am facing similar issues, and I am just worried that if I register a business I may end up having to pay tax / facing other issues...

Comment: @DianaVallverdu - I did not register my business, because my software is not associated with a business. I simply discontinued the Instagram part of my software. Based on my experience with Instagram from the past 10+ years, they are the worst when it comes to the TOS around their API. I didn't feel it was worth my effort to continue supporting them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#business-verification), business verification is required.

> While your app is in Development Mode it will only be able to access data in Instagram Tester accounts. Before you can switch your app to Live Mode and access data in non-tester accounts, you must first complete Business Verification.